# How to set the position of an image using the center of the image in pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am using python 2.7, and im using pygame to make a basic game.

(code can be found here: http://github.com/ProgrammerKid/snake)
(snake.py is my main file)

My game was initially supposed to mock the snake game, but it turned out to be more like pacman... so my problem is that since in pygame, the position of an image is always set to the top left corner of the image.... is there was i can make it the center of the image...

because the position of the killer/alien is at the top left, and same with the pacman/snake... so the two objects would literally have to be overlapping for the alien to kill the pacman.... i want it so that they only overlap a little....:
check out this picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N88GX.png

Answer (score 0):

see:  [Pygame Rect Reference](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

you probably already know:

```
imageObject = pygame.image.load(filename)
rect = imageObject.get_rect()
```

Now try:

```
rect.center = (newX, newY)
```

Or, better:

```
rect.move(xDistance, yDistance)
```

Good Luck!